# How to access fastapi.Request.state when using Pydantic.BaseModel

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to create a pydantic BaseModel that will be able to map some data from the request body and also from the request.state.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to accomplish? What do you want to map into the pydantic model? Is there any reason why you can't do it with the regular constructor / `__init__`, or with a helper method on your model?

Comment: I have a middleware that stores a request_id in Request.state and the client consuming my endpoint is expected to send me several parameters in a json as part of the post request. I wanted to create a pydantic model that will validate the input sent in the body of the request and also will have access to extract the request_id added by the middleware.

Comment: Why can't you add `request: Request` to the view method and access it from there, so that it's clear where the state arrives from? (i.e. `def my_method(item: Item, request: Request): ..`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @MatsLindh. It sure did the trick 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request metadata shouldn't be part of your model - the model should only be concerned with the *actual* request (i.e. the data submitted by the user).

To access metadata about the request, add a `Request` object to your view definition:

```
def my_method(item: Item, request: Request):
```

This will magically give you all the metadata (including the `.state` entry) under the `request` variable in your view function.